# How to add a textbox inside checkboxlist in C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Is is possible to add a textbox inside a checkbox list?

Here's the problem.
I am having a checkbox list in which I need to insert and show a text box if certain checkbox is clicked.
Say I have a list 
Item A
Item B
Item C
Item D

now if user check Item B then a text box should appear between Item B and Item C.
Any possibility doing this using C# or Jquery?

Gautam

Comment: So, are you using Webforms or MVC?

Comment: If it's a form that needs to be posted back to the server, the simplest solution is as following: include the textbox in the view, hide it (manually by CSS, or use jQuery's `hide` on `document.ready`), then use jQuery to hook up to 'change' event of the check box (`$("#YourCheckbox").change(function()...)`) and if it's 'checked' (`$("#YourCheckbox").is(":checked")`), show the textbox. (That's for MVC)

Comment: I am not using MVC.. Its a website. Its plain ASP.net using JQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use JQuery to achieve that:

Here's the HTML code:

```
a<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Daily" />
b<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Weekly" />
c<input id="test" type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Monthly" />
<input id="txtbox" type="text">
d<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Yearly" />
```

Here's the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

    function initialize() {
       $("input#txtbox").hide(); 
       $(":checkbox").click(countChecked);    
    }


    function countChecked() {
        if ($("input#test").is(':checked')) {
            $("input#txtbox").show();                
        }
        else {
            $("input#txtbox").hide(); 
        }
    }
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/s9vL6/2/)

[Here's the source of information](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. But in my case the values for checkbox list are coming from DB and hence I dont know exactly where i will have to put the Textbox..Anyhow, I am doing it the other way around now.. for the values where I need checkboxes with textbox I am putting those at end and then enabling disabling those using JS.

Comment: Very late reply but for anyone else looking: You can move the textbox to immediately follow the checkbox with jQuery's after() method.

$("input#test").after($("input#txtbox"))